# mongoose auto delete collection don't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to automatically delete a collection in mongoose. I have read the mongodb documentation and searched the web. I am not deleted. Please help me understand.

```
const SlotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
        expireAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            index: { expires: '60000' },
        }
},{timestamps: true})
```

and

```
const SlotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
        expireAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            index: { expires: 60 },
        }
},{timestamps: true})
```

and

```
const SlotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
}, {timestamps: true});
    
    SlotSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 });
```

After a minute, nothing happens. Why?

Comment: inistead of `index: { expires: '60000' },` what if `expires: 60`

Comment: @cmgchess Does not work :(

Comment: So you want the whole collection to be deleted after some time?

Comment: @AnkitPatel I'm not sure what the correct name is. I have a "Slot" schema. on button click i create 1 instance of "Slot". This 1 instance should be gone in a minute. Each instance has its own timer for a minute

Comment: ok, wait let me update my ans

Answer (score 0):

update your model as below.

```
const SlotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
}, {timestamps: true});
    
    SlotSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 });
```

I Have created a TTL index on the createdAt field, with an expiration time of 60 seconds (1 minute). This means that each document will be automatically deleted one minute after it was created.

Test it, i didn't have any test collection to test this code

also check this official [Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

my testing schema

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const withdrawalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
withdrawal_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: 'users'
},
Request_ammount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,

    default:0
},
Total_ammount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,

    default:0
},
Current_Ammount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default:0
},
admin_commission: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,

    default:0
},
Admin_PayTo_Vendor: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default:0
},
description:{
    type: String,
    required: false,
},
payout_date:{
    type: Date,
    required: false,
},
status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Rejected'],
    default: 'Pending'
}
}, { timestamps: true });

withdrawalSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 }); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('withdrawal', withdrawalSchema);
```

after updating the schema I just created a new instance and it got deleted in a minute

you can check your indexes in mongo
[image: Atlus img]

Comment: @Roman can you check the above,

Comment: try it and let me know, i didn't have any test collection to check it

Comment: Doesn't work :( A minute passes and the created instance of "Slot" is not deleted

Comment: it's working, i checked it

Comment: perfectly working as your need.

Comment: Doesn't work :( I'm looking for an answer for a very long time. I noticed that the creation date of the document does not have a time zone. Could this be a problem? Do you have the same? 
createdAt : 2023-04-03T10:07:26.057+00:00

Comment: The index is being created. The date field is in the document. But nothing gets deleted